# os.listdir, charder return can't encode characters

Tags: python

This is code (chardet(https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) - Universal encoding detector)

```
import chardet

try: 
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        print f, chardet.detect(f)['encoding'], f.decode(chardet.detect(f)['encoding'])
except Exception, e: 
    print str(e)
```

Output

```
qiwi2.sql ascii qiwi2.sql
www ascii www
’ҐЄбв®ўл© ¤®Єг¬Ґ­в.txt windows-1252 
'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-8: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the `print`. It doesn't know what encoding to use for the console output so it assumes `ASCII`, and does an `encode` automatically and fails. If you do the `encode` yourself it should work.

```
print f, chardet.detect(f)['encoding'], f.decode(chardet.detect(f)['encoding']).encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: But its doesnt work... :( Besides, `decode` return `UNICODE` and they can write without errors into ide console without encoded to something encoding.

Comment: @AlexKiselev, Unicode *must* be encoded before it can be written to output, since Unicode by itself is not an encoding. It's obvious by your error message that `ascii` is what Python is trying to use for the encoding. What is the exact symptom of "it doesn't work"?

Comment: The script returns the same result